# Nodejs Cluster with MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

Looking on advice on clustering of Nodejs and the method of connection to mysql server. Do we open one connection for each child process or just one single connection for all processes? Or do we create a connection pool for all the child processes? Which is the recommended method?

one node process

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

node cluster option 1:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  // open one connection for each process
  var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'example.org',
      user     : 'bob',
      password : 'secret'
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
      }

      console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    });
}
```

option2:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host            : 'example.org',
    user            : 'bob',
    password        : 'secret'
});

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {

  // accept http connections and query
  pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
     if (err) throw err;

     console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hong can you please repost this question for it go get more activity?

Comment: Hi NiCK are u looking for a solution to this?

Comment: I think so. Not sure to add them inside the cluster or master.

Comment: Hey @NiCkNewman, check my answer. I have been using the pattern and it seems to be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error, I'm using option 2 and it is working well. Created the connection globally and use in the cluster.

Each time you need to query, getConnection.

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error getting sql connection');
            console.dir(err);

            if(typeof connection !== "undefined")
                connection.release();

            callback(err);
        }

        if(typeof cb === "undefined") {
            //console.log('with 2 params');
            connection.query( sql, function(err, rows) {
                connection.release();
                console.dir(sql);
                // console.dir('data=>' + data);

                if(err) {
                    console.log('err:' + err);
                    callback(err, rows);
                }else{
                    console.log( rows );
                    callback(err, rows);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // console.log('with 3 params:' + cb);
            connection.query( sql, data, function(err, rows){
                connection.release();
                console.log(sql);
                console.dir(data);

                if(err) {
                    console.log('err:' + err);
                    callback(err, rows);
                }else{
                    console.log( rows );
                    callback(err, rows);
                }

            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pool will be recreated for every worker thread and you'll have multiple connection pools in your clustered application

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct answer is, that it all depends? If you run concurrent operations (async etc), you'd probably want a pool. But if you are just nesting queries, then a single shared connection should be fine.

I prefer to use pools (even inside workers), simply because you get some error handling and robustness for free (connections are recreated as they die, there is an operations queue with timeouts etc). I've not found any downsides to this, so far...