# NodeJS Clustering with Database connections

Tags: mysql, node.js, multithreading, database-connection, node-cluster

I have the question exactly as this one:
[Nodejs Cluster with MySQL connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339179/nodejs-cluster-with-mysql-connections)

I want to know what is the recommended approach to create database connections for nodejs clusters - either create one database connection to be shared across all workers, or to create one connection per worker.

The above thread doesn't answer this, rather it only answers what is 'working without issues'.

What I would like to know, is whether there are any scaling issues or concurrent-request issues that I would run into if I were to use any one of the 2 approaches when using MySQL database?

What is the approach that people are using at scale? Am I better off creating one connection per worker?